# A word for the application of a solution to an altogether different problem

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes one or both of the following situations:

- A researcher presents a new solution to a problem of his/her field of research by applying a strategy or idea used in an unrelated field of research for the first time.
- The solution to problem A or a derivative is applied to problem B, which is not related, but structurally similar in a way that the solution can be transferred.

Noun or adjective are both acceptible:

> The solution was found through *X=noun* with the research field of Meteorology.
>
> The *X=adjective* solution was inspired by the research field of Meteorology.

I have considered synergy, interdisciplinary, knowledge transfer and analogy. None of these fits.

Comment: a multivalent solution

Answer (score 1):

**cross-fertilization** (n.)

> Interaction or interchange, as between two or more cultures, fields of
> activity or knowledge, or the like, that is mutually beneficial and
> productive [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cross-fertilization)

> Interchange or interaction (as between different ideas, cultures, or
> categories) especially of a broadening or productive nature [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross-fertilization)

---

> Gregor Mendel was one of the first **biologists** to use mathematical
> analysis to prove hypotheses. He used elementary **probability** theory in
> his word. He was also inspired by the **atomic theory of matter** (an
> appropriate example of **cross-fertilization in science**). [D. Vaccari et al.; *Environmental Biology for Engineers and Scientists*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Environmental_Biology_for_Engineers_and/Z1QtmG2Li4cC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22%20Gregor%20Mendel%20was%20one%20of%20the%20first%20biologists%20to%20use%20mathematical%22&pg=PA116&printsec=frontcover) (2005)

> **Chemistry** proved as essential an ingredient to the new science of soft
> matter as ideas and techniques from **physics**, together with renewed
> conversation between the two sciences. Chemists brought not only the
> careful synthetic construction of the remarkable giant molecules and
> assemblies of soft materials but also ways of thinking about and
> characterizing the subtle forces between them. Arising from ancient
> technology, the imaginative leaps of individuals, and the
> **cross-fertilization of ideas**—including the final opening of a window onto the atomic world itself, imagined for so many centuries—it
> is not possible to tell a convincing story of the science of soft
> matter without visiting some more of its history in each case study.
> [Tom McLeish; *Soft Matter*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Soft_Matter_A_Very_Short_Introduction/VS8DEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Chemistry%20proved%20as%20essential%20an%20ingredient%20to%20the%20new%20science%20of%20soft%22&pg=PA6&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

> **Cross-fertilization** occurs when **new legal solutions** to existing problems are proffered using rules or or principles **from
> other areas of international law**. [Erika Techera; *Routledge
> Handbook of International Environmental Law*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Routledge_Handbook_of_International_Envi/F799K5LThfgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cross-fertilization%20provided%20the%20solution&pg=PA663&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

> Therefore, a **cross fertilization** between terrestrial applications
> and marine ones seems possible, which should result in more efficient,
> flexible and reliable ships. [A. Marino and V. Bucci; *Technology and
> Science for the Ships of the Future*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Technology_and_Science_for_the_Ships_of/M-RhDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cross-fertilization%20%20in%20the%20sciences%20provided%20the%20solution&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [**independent**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/independent):

> **1 b (1)** : not requiring or relying on something else : not contingent
>   // an *independent* conclusion

So (to borrow from both example sentences):

> The solution was found through *independent* research in the field of Meteorology.

Comment: Hmm, I would misinterpret this as "not sponsored by any company or third-party".

Comment: @Daerst The adjective can apply to any number of things; It certainly doesn't only apply to companies. (In fact, I've rarely encountered it in that context—and, when I have, it's been followed by, or somehow preceded by, *company*.) But if that's really a concern, you could say ***my*** *independent research*.

Comment: I see your thinking more clearly now. It certainly doesn't apply _only_ to companies, but given its ambiguity, that would have been my first guess. The latter one clarifies it, but could also be misunderstood as “based on research that I have published in other fields”.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge I think there is no specific terminology, though I suggest:

**Interdisciplinary solution**  "if the solution is used as it is in both fields"
**Transcendent solution**       " if the solution is used abstractly among fields"

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U.  This would benefit from citing your sources and a [tour] of the site and [help].

Answer (score 0):

Accomodation

The act of fitting or adapting, or the state of being fitted or adapted; adaptation; adjustment; - followed by to.

Comment: What's the source of this definition?

Comment: Please read our help on [how to reference material written by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Also: please make sure words are spelled correctly! It's also good to explain how your word would work as an answer to the question.